# Adding a div layer on top of a jquery carousel. Tough one

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, css-float

I have a tough one, well it's tough for me because I'm kinda new to the whole jQuery carousel thing, never built one before this project.

Here's my problem.

If you go to the  [TEST SITE](http://174.120.239.48/~peakperf) you will see a scroller with a blue background about half way down the page. If you mouse onto the "data analytics" slide you should see a black box fade in.

Here is my dilemma. I want that black box to be a menu that's connected to the data analytics slide. I've done a mock up for you so you can see what I'm talking about.

[image]

Here is my scroller code. I'm using jCarousel.

```
 <div class="carousel">

 <ul>
     <li>
          <div id="homeslide1">
     testers sdfasdfasdfas asdftjhs iasndkad kasdnf
     <a href="#" id="#homeslide1-toggle">Close this</a>  </div>  
     <a href="#" id="homeslide1-show"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/home_data_analytics.jpg" width="200" height="94" /></a>


     </li>
     <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/home_oem_partnerships.jpg" width="200" height="94" /></li>
     <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/home_reporting.jpg" width="200" height="92" /></li>
     <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/home_returning_lost_customers.jpg" width="200" height="92" /></li>
     <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/home_sales.jpg" width="200" height="92" /></li>
     <li><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/home_service_retention.jpg" width="200" height="92" /></li>
  </ul>
```

Here is my scroller css

```
 /*HOMEPAGE SCROLLER*/
  .carousel {!important padding:10px; width: 890px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 26px;}
  .carousel ul li element.style{height: 94px;}
.carousel ul{width: 200px; padding: 5px;}
.carouselitem{height: 94px;}
.prev{background: url(images/home_left_scroll.png); height: 94px; width: 16px; text-indent: -999px; outline: none; cursor:pointer; float: left;}
.next{background: url(images/home_right_scroll.png); height: 94px; width: 16px; text-indent: -999px; outline: none; cursor:pointer; float: right;}
.carousel ul li{ padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px; margin: 0px; height:!important 94px;
}
.home_right_arrow{
     width: 16px;
     float: right;}
    .home_left_arrow{
     width: 16px;
     float: left;}
.homeslide1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 94px;}
```

I've tried all sorts of z-index tricks but can't seem to figure it out on my own. If you solve this riddle I'll buy you a beer if we ever meet up. I'll also give you a high five through the internet.

Is there a simple way to do this via jQuery? If so could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much.

Comment: could be a generic absolute positioning issue -> if you just do it x pixels from the left and from the top...

Comment: The problem with taht is that it doesn't attach to the slide. Every slide is going to have one of those divs so i don't think absolute position would do the trick here.

Comment: What do you want to happen when it scrolls off the screen? And do you want it to scroll with the slide when scrolling normally?

Comment: @crimson   It will open on mouseover and fadeout on mouseout,so it won't stay open.

Comment: Ok, that makes it easier then!

Answer (score 1):

I was going to make an example using your site, but the code is too hard to navigate. So basically, you just need to get the position of the linking element with [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset), and then use it to set the offset of the menu. So yes, use absolute positioning; it's by far the easiest way this will work. You may also need to make your `a` fill up the whole space by making it `display: block;` and setting its dimensions.

Here's [an example](http://www.happyspork.com/sites/offset_example.html). When making it I found that for some reason the offset got applied relative to the old location when it was used more than once. I can't explain why, but using `.css(left: x, top: y)` instead for setting the location worked.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I'll try this and see if it works. I've never used offset before so I hope I can understand it and get this project done and over with :) Thanks again!

Comment: Been trying this all morning and still can't get it. Do you happen to know where I can find an example, maybe that will help me wrap my head around it a little more.